# Error while running python test from Build Pipeline - TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'client_options'

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, azure-devops, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-datastore

Running python test where i have used google-cloud-datastore in my code, so is this error specific to version?

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'client_options'
```

How to fix this error?

Comment: Can you add the actual code and full traceback? Hard to give any advice without it...

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko this is Azure DevOps Pipeline and inside this pipeline there is one task which is executing python unit test on our cloud application/code. There are number of test files and that too running properly from local configured machine(cloud setup), but once it triggered from pipeline on Linux build machine it was failing. I hope this explanation is helpful because cant post private code here.

Comment: I have a similar problem and it's really hard to use this question/answer without any sample code. Maybe you can copy/paste and fake the related lines of code.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I have solved this problem by updating/upgrading below libraries,

previous versions:

```
google-cloud-core==1.3.0
google-cloud-datastore==1.14.0
```

new versions:

```
google-cloud-core==1.4.1
google-cloud-datastore==1.15.0
```

so we could say error was because of version mismatch in google library that was used in our code.

Comment: Hi Vinod, 
Thanks for the sharing, you could accept your answer, In this case, others could directly find the useful solution.

Comment: I ran into this same issue using beam/dataflow but needed to update the REQUIRED_PACKAGES list in setup.py to match the output of `pip freeze`.

Comment: This helped when I was getting the same error message when trying to connect dbt to my google bigQuery account. I used pip3 install 'new-versions-listed-above'. Thanks

Comment: This helped me resolve a similar issue deploying Cloud Functions. I ended up changing the syntax of my requirement versions from "==" to ">=".